# Debugging a Service Fabric application against a remote on-premises cluster using VS 2019

Tags: azure-service-fabric, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2019

The development machine does not have enough capacity to host and run the Service Fabric cluster on the same machine where VS 2019 installed. So, a possible workaround would be having the cluster created on the local network (not Azure) and debug it remotely. Is it a feasible scenario, and if so how we can configure VS 2019 to remotely debug the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a doc for remote debugging a SF application using VS

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-debugging-your-application#debug-a-remote-service-fabric-application

It doesn't appear it has been updated for VS 2019 though so some steps might be a bit different. But it is possible and should give you a place to start.

Comment: thanks for sharing the link. Per the article the remote debugging to SF hosted on Azure was explained. Does it apply to a cluster hosted on Windows Servers within a company network not on Azure?

Comment: Yes it still applies. Just instead of selecting the cluster in Azure you should be able to browse on your local network and find the cluster.